# what is the difference between count(*) and count(1) in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi all i am newbie in `SQL`?
What is the difference between count(*) and count(1) in `SQL`?

Thank You

Comment: answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1

Answer (score 3):

**There is no difference.**

```
Select Count(*) from TableName
Select Count(1) from TableName
```

It is very common perception that the Count(1) perform better compared to Count(*), however it is not the case. If you test by looking at the execution plan, you will see same action being performed by both the commands and same number of rows being scanned. The time taken may be slightly different interms of CPU usage for count(*) , but is almost same as count(1). The confusion is generally because in older version of some RDBMS products like Oracle has difference in performance for select count(*) and count(1), but recent releases does not have any difference.

Refer this : 
http://www.sqlserverf1.com/difference-between-select-count-and-count1-in-sql-server/

and

[Count(*) vs Count(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1)

Comment: What are the differences ?

Comment: @bilal There is no difference. .. Check the post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1

Comment: I think the confusion over the execution cost is also due to `SELECT *` being generally more expensive than `SELECT 1` or `SELECT intColumn`. Of course, `COUNT(*)` would have specific optimizing code in the parser/engine, which would recognize that there is no need to fetch the contents of every column.